# "Expected unqualified-id" in #define statement

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to simplify my code by using `#define` statements. This is because it contains a lot of repetitive "chunks" of code that cannot be repeated using the obvious alternative, functions, because in these chunks, variables need to be declared like you'd do in a `#define` statement, e.g. `#define dostuff(name) int name##Variable;`.

---

### Code

```
#define createBody(name,type,xpos,ypos,userData,width,height) b2BodyDef name##BodyDef;\
name##BodyDef.type = type==@"dynamic"?b2_dynamicBody:b2_staticBody;\
name##BodyDef.position.Set(xpos,ypos);\
name##BodyDef.userData = userData;\
name=world->CreateBody(&name##BodyDef);\
b2PolygonShape name##shape;\
name##shape.SetAsBox(width/ptm_ratio/2,height/ptm_ratio/2);
```

... and applying that in the following:

```
createBody(block, @"dynamic", winSize.width*5/6/ptm_ratio, winSize.height*1/6/ptm_ratio, ((__bridge void*)blockspr), blockspr.contentSize.width, blockspr.contentSize.height)
//                                                               error  appears  there:  ^
```

Now my point is that everything's working great, no errors, except a single one that's freaking me out:

> Expected unqualified-id

which points at the first bracket in `((__bridge ...`, as indicated. (That argument gets passed via the `userData` argument to `createBody`.)

I know this code is nowhere near simple, but since everything else is working, I believe that an answer must exist.

This is my first question on SO, so if there's anything unclear or insufficient, please let me know!

Comment: Is that Objective-C hiding under all that... stuff?

Comment: Haha it is :) I'll edit the tags

Comment: Thanks for updating the tags. Honestly, it looks like you're trying to fix the wrong problem. You should be spending your energy on trying to redesign your code so that you don't need all those generated variable names, not trying to fix those macro things.

Comment: The point is that the chunk of code needs to be repeated lots of times (I'm talking about 10 to maybe 15 times) right after each other. Of course I could just repeat those chunks and don't mind, but I wanted to figure out if there was a more concise way of doing that annoying repeating of the same recipe.

Comment: The repetition is the root of your issue. But hiding that repetition in a macro is not a good solution. You need to figure out how to change your code to make it doable in a proper function. I don't see anything in your macro that prevents this, except the generated names and those you can do away with by passing references or pointers to a function.

Comment: Do you think it would be reasonable to make one BIG array (of objects!) and make a function to stuff those variables, that are now generated, in the "next" item in that array? (Just to make it possible to use a function here, that is.)

Comment: Yes, that would be an approach (using an enum to give nice names to the indexes). Using a dictionary with meaningful key names would be another.

Comment: This is becoming an "extended discussion" :)
I'll think about trying the array approach or just leaving it as it is :) Anyway, do you still have any clue as to what that stupid error means? After looking around it seems like it can mean a million things...

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to simplify my code by using #define statements.

This sounds an alarm in my mind.

Break this down into functions. You said you can't. I say you can.

Notice that your macro here:

```
createBody(name,type,xpos,ypos,userData,width,height);
```

It has **exactly** the same syntax as a C function. So you've already created a function, you only declared it as a macro. There's no reason why you couldn't rewrite it as a function (C or Objective-C doesn't matter). You do not need to give each body its own name, instead you could store them in a dictionary (careful though because Box2D takes ownership of the bodies).

Comment: How would I go about creating such a dictionary? Alloc-init an NSDictionary and adding keys with the names of my current variables with as values the bodies (and fixures, to which this method applies as well)? Do I run into ownership or similar type problems then?

Comment: As a side note, does _anyone_ know what that stupid error means?